# When I edit the XML file with my VB code, the original structure is gone and all nodes are written in a single line

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I wrote a code in VBA to parse and write a XML file nodes into a sheet in Excel, and then I tried to do the oppposite, catching the range values and putting into the same file again. It works, but it turned out to not preserve the structure. This is what I mean:

Original XML:

```
<data name="Abrangencia" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Abrangência</value>
</data>
<data name="AbrangenciaDaMudanca" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Abrangência da Mudança</value>
</data>
<data name="AbrangenciaMoc" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Abrangência MoC</value>
</data>
<data name="AbreParenteses" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Abre Parênteses</value>
</data>
<data name="Acao" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Ação</value>
</data>
```

After the rewritting code:

```
 <data name="Abrangencia"><value>Abrangência</value></data><data name="AbrangenciaDaMudanca">      <value>Abrangência da Mudança</value></data><data name="AbrangenciaMoc"><value>Abrangência MoC</value></data><data name="AbreParenteses"><value>Abre Parênteses</value></data><data name="Acao"><value>Ação</value></data><data name="AcaoDeMitigacao"><value>Ação de Mitigação</value></data>
```

So it basically is not breaking lines and also don't know if I was supposed to add this xml:space="preserve" as a attribute also (I don't even program myself, just trying to learn somethings). This is my code as it is:

```
Sub RefreshXML()
Dim vFolder As String, vFile As String, vFileName As String
Dim vLineFile As Integer, vLineTAG As Integer, vData As Integer
Dim vRange As String, vNode As String, vRange2 As String
Dim vWindowMain As String, vWindowFile As String, vWindowXML As String, vXMLSheetName As String
Dim XDoc As Object
Dim myNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, myChildNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim myElement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim myNode As IXMLDOMNode, myChildNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NameItem As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim nNode As Integer
Dim nChildNode As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

vWindowMain = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Abrindo a outra planilha que receberá os nodulos
Sheets("Plan1").Select
vRange = "A1"
vXMLSheetName = Range(vRange).Value + "Orionv5.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open vXMLSheetName, UpdateLinks:=False
vWindowXML = ActiveWorkbook.Name
vLineFile = 2

'main workbook
Windows(vWindowMain).Activate
Sheets("Plan1").Select
vRange = "A1"
vFolder = Range(vRange).Value
vLineTAG = 2
vData = 0

Do While True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    vLineFile = vLineFile + 1
    Windows(vWindowMain).Activate
    Sheets("Plan1").Select
    vRange = "A" + Trim(Str(vLineFile))
    vFile = Range(vRange).Value
    vFileName = vFolder + "\" + vFile 'xml arquives are listed on the main workbook
    
    If vFile = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set wb = Workbooks(vWindowXML)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.load (vFileName)
    XDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True
    Set myNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//data")
    For nNode = 0 To myNodes.Length - 1
        Set myNode = myNodes(nNode)
        myNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild myNode
        XDoc.Save vFileName
    Next nNode
    
    Do While True
        With ws
            vRange2 = "B" + Trim(Str(vLineTAG))
            Set myNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//root")
            Set myElement = XDoc.createElement("data")
            myNode.appendChild myElement
            Set myNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//root/data")
            Set NameItem = XDoc.createAttribute("name")
            NameItem.NodeValue = .Range(vRange2).Value
            Set myNode = myNodes(vData)
            myNode.Attributes.setNamedItem NameItem
            vRange2 = "C" + Trim(Str(vLineTAG))
            Set myNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//data")
            Set myElement = XDoc.createElement("value")
            myElement.Text = .Range(vRange2).Value
            Set myNode = myNodes(vData)
            myNode.appendChild myElement
            vRange2 = "A" + Trim(Str(vLineTAG))
            XDoc.Save vFileName
            vLineTAG = vLineTAG + 1
            vData = vData + 1
            If .Range(vRange2).Value <> vFile Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End With
        
    Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

I thought that the simple line XDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True would solve my problem, as I saw it work for another person in some other forum, but it did not. How could I preserve the original structure of the arquive? And also, should I add the xml:space="preserve" to the node as an attribute (like, is this relevant information for the XML)?

Comment: Your output XML is not well-formed. It has no **root** element. So it cannot be indented by definition.

Comment: It has, I'm just showing some lines of it. it has more then 800 nodes.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 
    
    Version 2.0
    
    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.
  This is the beggining

Comment: I just showed the nodes that I'm updating, the ones above or below the data ones are nonrelevant

Comment: You can check this link: http://vb-helper.com/howto_formatted_xml_document.html